# TextBox change on selection text

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have in `TextBox`with value of time of my audio.
It looks like this:
"00:00:00.000"
it's format `hh:mm:ss.fff`, where `fff` = miliseconds.

I need to do in my `ViewModel` that when I click on hours or minutes or seconds I can change only these values which I select, but cannot remove `:` or `.`.
Length of hours, minutes and seconds must be max 2 numbers each one and miliseconds = 3 numbers.

Can someone help me to do this?
Thanks a lot.

EDITED:
I would like make textbox works like "change time" in Windows 7

Comment: What do you mean by *"when they click on hours or minutes or seconds"*?

Comment: I would break it up into 4 textboxes with the ":" and "." as textblocks between them. Each time component would be an integer property in the viewmodel. And maybe add another property that combines them into your "00:00:00.000" format. You can set the max length of the textboxes to 2 (or 3 for ms). The bindings to integer properties should keep the values numeric.

Comment: What you are asking is unclear

Answer (score 0):

You just need MaskedTextBox
otherwise you should create an usercontrol manulaly with desire functions